# How to find all files in a folder which do not have a specific character in the ending of their file names?

Tags: powershell

I have a file share with McAfee FRP encrypted files and folders and due to an unknown issue, some of the files were added with a special character `''` in the ending of their files names.(example: `helloworld.txt` instead of `helloworld.txt`) I am tryng to find out the files that do not have the special char `''` in the ending of the file name.

I have tried using the below powershell command to find the files ending with `''`.

Here is the command: `Get-ChildItem * . * -Recurse`

However, I want to find the files not ending with special character `''` and I am unable to negate the above command to get what I want using (`NOT, ! and ~`)

Files in the folder are as below:

```
helloworld.ppt, McAfee_test.txt, Data.txt, testabc.xlxs, doneDone.jpeg, test1.txt, hello.xml, ok123.mp3
```

The above comand will return the below result:

```
test1.txt, testabc.xlxs, helloworld.ppt, ok123.mp3
```

Which command will retun the below result ?

```
McAfee_test.txt, Data.txt, doneDone.jpeg, hello.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-Exclude` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Exclude *
```